# Cloudflare connection timeout on curl request

Tags: curl, cloudflare, guzzle

I am sending request with guzzle (curl) to API which is behind CloudFlare.

When I send requests sometimes I receive:

cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 120001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

If I resend the same request, it will pass most probably without connection timeout.

How can I debug this issue? What can be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: you need to provide more details some specific reason is hard to tell with the info you provided, if you want that timeout is unset then pass request options `timeout` as 0

Comment: @bhucho, any specific information? Not sure what information is relevant.

Comment: you need to show your code first, the guzzle part to make debugging a bit easier